# Writing list of items to excel sheet by separating with comma

Tags: python

I am using xlwt package and I want to export lists to excel spreadsheet which can be written in single cells separated by comma , just like the spreadsheet below:

```
id=['1','2','3','4']
sheet1.write(0, 0,'id')
sheet1.write(0, 1,id)

EXCEL OUTPUT

A    B
id  1,2,3,4
```

Current output is 1234 without any comma

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to write items in list in a particular column separated by comma

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this, and what problems have you faced?

Comment: Update your question showing your current result and the expected result.

Comment: Updated the current ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the cell to be formatted correctly you should use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method from the string library.

You could then do something like:

```
>>> id = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x = ",".join(str(i) for i in id)
>>> x
'1,2,3,4'
```

If *id* is a string instead:

```
>>> id = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
>>> x = ",".join(id)
>>> x
'1,2,3,4'
```

You can then do to get the right output:

```
sheet1.write(0, 1, x)
```

I am assuming that it is something like this you want.

Comment: I had the updated the input also as a string but still when i write in excel its coming as 1234 without comma